# TPT TERADATA ACCEPT MISSING COLUMNS IN CSV FILE

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a question regarding the tpt teradata,

I have a CSV file that I want to upload via the TPT.

This file can have 4 or 5 columns (5th column is optional)

Is it possible to load csv files via tpt, and put NULL when the 5th field is absent in the file?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the *AcceptMissing Columns* option in the TPT DATACONNECTOR operator

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution indeed :)